# Amazon S3 Bucket - This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm storing some pdf files in an Amazon S3 bucket and accessing them through my website. When I click on some documents saved in the same place, they open normally. However, one in particular is giving me this error:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>BW2VS1WEE21AM0Q9</RequestId>
<HostId>Xp1DGhbsrkdLN3F43i/u2741UJrfZUcCIyL57nXUL89A+seXkT5cyJ8OBslFwqw4ObsDr45UQPw=</HostId>
</Error>
```

It is in the function of editing the data of a certain user of the system, which has documents stored.

```
public function update(BeneficiadoRequest $request, $id)  {

$aluno = Beneficiados::find($id);
$projeto = Projeto::find($aluno->projeto_id);

if($request->ativo == 'Inativo' && $aluno->ativo == 'Ativo') {
  $aluno->data_inativo = Carbon::now();      
  $aluno->ativo = $request->ativo;
} else {
  $aluno->ativo = $request->ativo;
}

$aluno->fill($request->all());
$aluno->nome = mb_strtoupper($request->nome);
$aluno->entrada = $request->entrada;

$aluno->saida = $request->saida;
$aluno->modalidade = $request->modalidade;
$aluno->turma_id = $request->turma;
$aluno->save();

$documentos = DocumentosAluno::where('beneficiado_id', $id)->first();

if ($request->hasFile('documento_foto34') && $request->file('documento_foto34')->isValid()) {

  $name = str_replace('+', '', $request->file('documento_foto34')->getClientOriginalName());
  $foto = $request->documento_foto34->storeAs('/' . $projeto->titulo . '/documentos_alunos/' . $aluno->id . '-' . $aluno->rg, $name, 's3');
  $documentos->foto = $foto;
}
if ($request->hasFile('documento_identidade') && $request->file('documento_identidade')->isValid()) {
  $name = str_replace('+', '', $request->file('documento_identidade')->getClientOriginalName());
  $identidade = $request->documento_identidade->storeAs('/' . $projeto->titulo . '/documentos_alunos/' . $aluno->id . '-' . $aluno->rg, $name, 's3');
  $documentos->identidade = $identidade;
}
if ($request->hasFile('documento_identidade_verso') && $request->file('documento_identidade_verso')->isValid()) {
  $name = $request->file('documento_identidade_verso')->getClientOriginalName();
  $identidade_verso = $request->documento_identidade_verso->storeAs('/' . $projeto->titulo . '/documentos_alunos/' . $aluno->id . '-' . $aluno->rg, $name, 's3');
  $documentos->identidade_verso = $identidade_verso;
}
if ($request->hasFile('cpf') && $request->file('cpf')->isValid()) {
  $name = $request->file('cpf')->getClientOriginalName();
  $cpf = $request->cpf->storeAs('/' . $projeto->titulo . '/documentos_alunos/' . $aluno->id . '-' . $aluno->rg, $name, 's3');
  $documentos->cpf = $cpf;
}
if ($request->hasFile('documento_residencia') && $request->file('documento_residencia')->isValid()) {
  $name = str_replace('+', '', $request->file('documento_residencia')->getClientOriginalName());
  $residencia = $request->documento_residencia->storeAs('/' . $projeto->titulo . '/documentos_alunos/' . $aluno->id . '-' . $aluno->rg, $name, 's3');
  $documentos->residencia = $residencia;
}
if ($request->hasFile('documento_medico') && $request->file('documento_medico')->isValid()) {
  $name = str_replace('+', '', $request->file('documento_medico')->getClientOriginalName());
  $medico = $request->documento_medico->storeAs('/' . $projeto->titulo . '/documentos_alunos/' . $aluno->id . '-' . $aluno->rg, $name, 's3');
  $documentos->atestado_medico = $medico;
}
if ($request->hasFile('documento_matricula') && $request->file('documento_matricula')->isValid()) {
  $name = str_replace('+', '', $request->file('documento_matricula')->getClientOriginalName());
  $matricula = $request->documento_matricula->storeAs('/' . $projeto->titulo . '/documentos_alunos/' . $aluno->id . '-' . $aluno->rg, $name, 's3');
  $documentos->comprovante_matricula = $matricula;
}
if ($request->hasFile('documento_termo') && $request->file('documento_termo')->isValid()) {
  $name = str_replace('+', '', $request->file('documento_termo')->getClientOriginalName());
  $termo = $request->documento_termo->storeAs('/' . $projeto->titulo . '/documentos_alunos/' . $aluno->id . '-' . $aluno->rg, $name, 's3');
  $documentos->termo_ficha = $termo;
}
$documentos->save();


return redirect()->back();
```

}

Comment: When you download the PDF from an Amazon S3 bucket in the AWS Management Console and open it, is the PDF valid in Adobe Reader?

Comment: Yes. I download both pdf and jpg and both open normally

Comment: Are you using code to get the PDF displayed. If so - you should show the community the logic that you are using.

Comment: I already edited.

Answer (score 0):

https://night.kr-cell.com/...

<

This XML file does not appear to have any style informati

▼

`InvalidBucketName` The specified bucket is not valid. </Mess

648831368DA3F63938C7D52B night.kr-cell.com privacy.html <EC 0015-00000001

Comment: It looks like your answer went through some formatting problems, you might want to paste it again, but format the html tags within `code` tags so it'll be visible and clear.